# How to set missing serial number on MacBook Pro 2014

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, serial-number

My MacBook pro model 2014 mid 15 inches, has lost serial number during upgrading the OS.
I am having Catalina Os installed on the machine and have tried with a guide that tells about the [Blank board serializer](http://rogersm.net/icloud-problems-mountain-lion-serial-number) I write it to USB drive and when boot up the machine, Clicked EFI BOOT start normally nothing effect.
All I want any other way of setting back my serial number.
I am struggling for the last one month to fix the issue please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

If your MacBook is not properly serialized it should be done by an Apple Authorised Service Provider. It is to be assumed that perhaps it was forgotten (or not properly done) after a repair.

Comment: I think I ask for a solution, not the reason, I already aware how this comes all I Need a solution this is not answer to my question there is no authorized service provider in every country

Comment: Call AppleCare, see if they can pick it up/ship it. If there was a mistake during a repair they might cover the cost.

Comment: it's not due to repair I am sure I have high Seira and it was fine when I upgrade it to Catalina this loss of serial number occurred

Comment: @AbdulManan - is your serial number shown in "About This Mac" (first option from the Apple Logo in the top left of your screen)

Comment: no its not showing no where

Comment: The board can only be serialized once and the serial number cannot be deleted or overwritten after, so this did not happen through an update. The software required is only available to AASPs in an official capacity. So the only proper, official way to do this is through an AASP. Any other way of doing it will most likely void any claim to services from Apple (both in or out of warranty). Furthermore, sharing the software would be against its licensing and therefor not allowed on StackExchange.

Comment: I have high Seira ,Mojave and I saw my serial number was there once I upgraded to Catalina I found someday after that my serial number is gone.
we don't have any AASP in our area so it will be great if anyone could guide me to do it my self

Comment: @KevinGrabher, "so this did not happen through an update". Unfortunately, I believe you are likely wrong on this, as I am encountering the exact same issue, with my serial number nowhere to be found via "about this mac" or using terminal commands. I have created a new post regarding the issue. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409164/macbook-pro-11-3-no-longer-has-a-serial-number. Please help if you have any advice.